# Error: Request failed with status code 400 when expo buidl

Tags: build, expo

When you build expo you can face an error:
at createError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/turtle-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:322:22)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1187:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that project is not published to Expo website.

You have to publish project first :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).